# ctypes.CDLL() works from anaconda python installation but not from "raw" python installation

Tags: python, anaconda, ctypes

I have a curious problem concerning the use of ctypes:
The behavior of ctypes varies depending on whether i use the python installation from anaconda or the "raw" python installation from python.org (both on Windows 10).

To reproduce: Simply go to anaconda.com, install anaconda (and anaconda python) via the default installer. Go to python.org and install python via the default installer.

The anaconda installation comes with the mingw(x64) binaries which are required for at least some .dll (i don't know too much here but at least the dll that i'm working with requires them). The "raw" python does not have these so they need to be added manually (Required are some or all (didn't check) of: libatomic-1.dll, libgccc_s_seh-1.dll, libgomp-1.dll, libquadmath-0.dll, libssp-0.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll, simply copy them into the directory you are working or add their directory to PATH).

Now you have two versions of python, each with their own version of ctypes (my anaconda python has version 3.8.8, "raw" python has version 3.9.5, ctypes has version 1.1.0 for both).

Trying to load a dll via the anaconda python, like:

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.CDLL(<insertdllname>)
```

Works completely fine (provided you are working in the directory of the dll, otherwise you need to specify the full path).

Trying the same with the "raw" python installation fails. The issue being that ctypes from the "raw" python cannot find the mingw libraries that the to-be-loaded dll depends upon. This is despite those libraries being in working directory (or explicitely adding their folder to PATH)(both work when using anaconda python). Only when putting the additional libraries in the folder of the python installation (where "python.exe" is) they are found.

Now when i copy the ctypes folder from the anaconda installation to where the ctypes folder of the "raw" installation is (renaming ctypes from the "raw" installation to ctypes_raw), i have two versions of ctypes available.

Using:

```
import ctypes_roh
ctypes_roh.CDLL(<insertdllname>)
```

Fails, as above.

```
import ctypes
ctypes.CDLL(<insertdllname>)
```

Works, so apparently the two ctypes libraries are different, with ctypes from the anaconda installation being able to look for dll in the working directory and in PATH, which ctypes from the "raw" python installation cannot do.

```
import ctypes
import ctypes_raw
ctypes.CDLL(<insertdllname>)
ctypes_raw.CDLL(<insertdllname>)
```

Now both calls work. Apparently, calling CDLL from anaconda ctypes fixes whatever prevents CDLL from "raw" ctypes from looking for dll in working directory or PATH.

So my questions are:

- Is there a reason why ctypes from the anaconda installation of python and the "raw" python installation as from python.org should be different?
- What are the differences? Why does ctypes from "raw" python fail to look for dll in working directory or PATH? Why does calling ctypes from anaconda python "fix" this issue?

EDIT: After finding out that the "raw" python installation doesn't have the needed mingw libraries i rewrote the post to account for that and to (hopefully) clarify the remaining question.

Comment: Do `import sys; print(sys.maxsize)` in both Pythons. What does each one print?

Comment: 9223372036854775807 for Anaconda installation.

Comment: 9223372036854775807 for  "raw" installation

Comment: Some key aspects are missing. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details.

Comment: Could you tell me which key aspects i missed? Given that you linked "How to create a minimal, reproducible example" i assume you are missing that in my post? I would argue that i did provide information about how to reproduce the problem, but maybe it wasn't clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

In the [conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/use-shared-libraries.html) for using shared libraries, different approaches are described depending on the operating system.  On Linux, shared libraries in conda packages typically have a modified rpath (using [patchelf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54723461/6338809)). For example:

```py
>>> import importlib.util
>>> importlib.util.find_spec("_ctypes").origin
'<$CONDA_PREFIX>/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
```

```bash
$ cd $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/
$ ldd _ctypes.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe565c0000)
        libffi.so.8 => not found
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fadad8de000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fadad6c2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fadad2f4000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fadadae2000)
```

Since libffi is not found, in python an `import ctypes` will give the error: `ImportError: libffi.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Now, libffi is installed as a conda package in this case, so

```bash
$ patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN/../..' _ctypes.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

will fix that problem.  Now if I create a shared library `test.c`:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

void special()
{
    printf("special\n");
}
```

and compile it i.e. `cc -shared -fPIC -o special.so test.c`, Then `special.so` will exist in this directory but ctypes won't be able to find it.  Now, if I do `cp special.so $CONDA_PREFIX/lib`, then in Python loading it works fine:

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("special.so")
<CDLL 'special.so', handle f86430 at 0x7ff44691e5f0>
>>> libsp = ctypes.CDLL("special.so")
>>> x = libsp.special()
special
```

On windows, to answer your specific question, the documentation states:

> This path [`(install prefix)\\Library\\bin`] is added to os.environ["PATH"] for all Python processes, so that DLLs can be located, regardless of the value of the system's PATH environment variable.
> This is the difference between the "raw" and the conda installation.

See also: [How does conda work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27753898/6338809)